# Can I sort an array in O(n) if all values are positive and with digits <= k?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, big-o

Supposing I have an array A[1 ... n] , and no range for its values apart from the fact that they are positive. If I know they have up to k digits, is it possible to sort array in O(n)?

All examples I have come across for O(n) sorting give an upper bound for the values in the array. If there is a duplicate please let me know.

Comment: If you know that they have k digits then you have an upper bound for the range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether k is a constant or not.

If your numbers have k digits each, then you do have a bound on the numbers, since they can't be any bigger than 10<sup>k</sup> - 1. You could therefore use [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) to sort the integers. The runtime of radix sort is O((n + b)log<sub>b</sub> U), where n is the number of numbers to sort, b is the base of your radix sort, and U is the maximum value that you're sorting. In your case, that works out to

> O((n + b) log<sub>b</sub> 10<sup>k</sup>) = O(k(n + b)).

This is where the "it depends" comes in. If k is some fixed number that never changes - say, it's always 137 or something like that - then the above expression reduces to O(n + b), and picking b to be any constant (say, base-2 for your radix sort) gives a runtime of O(n). On the other hand, if k can vary (say, the numbers are allowed to be as big as you'd like them to be, and then after seeing the numbers you work out what k is), then the above expression can't be simplified beyond O(kn) because k is a parameter to the algorithm.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If `k <= n`, you can, otherwise it's not guaranteed.

If I give you `n = 4` and `k = 5`, where would you place an element 3?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "where would you place an element 3." Can you elaborate?

Comment: Means you cannot guess where you would place 3, so you need to check in the elements you were given.

Comment: If `k - n = x`, you cannot know for sure where any of these `x` elements will be, so your complexity grows beyond linear.